# How to install Zentyal on remote Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 13.04, vpn, vps

I`m noob in linux, so be patient )))).
How to install it on VPS (Ubuntu 13.04, OPENVZ)? Do I have to download image firstly to server and run it or should I install it from Ubuntu repository? I have only SSH connection to server.
And how to connect to zentyal after installation? I know that have to set up vpn.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the ISO, and boot from it in your virtual container. You can get the latest ISO here:
http://www.zentyal.org/server/